# Creating matrix for scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata

Tags: python, scipy, distance, cluster-analysis

I am trying to run a cluster analysis on a list of coordinates. I'd like to use scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata. How do I create an appropriate n by m data matrix from my coordinates?

My list looks something like this:

```
list=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata.html), fclusterdata takes an array with shape (n, m) where n is the number of observations and m is the dimension of a given data point.

If you pass your list to `numpy.array`, the data is arranged in the proper shape.

```
>>> np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]).shape
(3, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata on the list:               spcluster.hierarchy.fclusterdata(list,10.0,method='ward')           but I get the following error:                                                           File "/appl64/python2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py", line 623, in linkage
    raise ValueError("Valid methods when the raw observations are "
ValueError: Valid methods when the raw observations are omitted are 'single', 'complete', 'weighted', and 'average'.                      What am I doing incorrectly now?

Comment: What is ``list``? That should be your data in the form of a numpy array, and you should definitely not name that variable ``list``.

Comment: sorry, it is my data (in the right form), and in the actual program it's named appropriately. I just used 'list' as an example

Comment: Not sure. Someone else seems to have had a similar problem though: http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1272